# Select multiple childs and subchilds when selecting root checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, parent-child, checkbox

javascript(jquery)

```
$('.ic_parent').change(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('value')
  while (id.length >0){
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
      $('#update_ics_table').find('input:checkbox[id = "child-of-' + id + '"]').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
    }else{
      $('#update_ics_table').find('input:checkbox[id = "child-of-' + id + '"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    id = $('#update_ics_table').find('input:checkbox[id = "child-of-' + id + '"]').attr('value')
  }
});
```

I have this treetable and would like to have cascade checkbox select.

When I click on the root its suppose to click all the children like so

```
root(selected)
  --child1(selected)
    -----subchild1(selected)
    -----subchild2(selected)
    -----subchild3(selected)
  --child2(selected)
    -----subchild1(selected)
    -----subchild2(selected)
```

My current code doesn't check the subchild1 and 2 for the child2

How would I modify my code so that this is possible?

SOLVED:

Ok this hopefully helps people who came across this post hoping to implement such treetable. F. Calderan pointed out a good code but it was only doing half the job as if you click a parent instead of grandparent, nothing happens.

```
$('.blah).live('change',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('value')
  var state = $(this).attr('checked')
  var plat = $(this).attr('platform')
  child_checker = $('#update_cycles_table').find('input:checkbox[key ^= "child-of-' + id + '_'+plat+'"]').attr('checked')
  if (child_checker == "checked"){
    $(this).removeAttr('checked')
  }
  while (id.length >0){
    if (state){
      $('#update_cycles_table').find('input:checkbox['+key+' ^= "child-of-' + id + '_'+plat+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked')    
    }else{
      $('#update_cycles_table').find('input:checkbox['+key+' ^= "child-of-' + id + '_'+plat+'"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
  id=($('#update_cycles_table').find('input:checkbox['+key+' ^= "child-of-' + id + '_'+plat+'"]').attr('value'));
  }
});
```

you also need a childcheck to makesure that when you click middle of the tree, the top also gets unchecked. Without the checker it will not recognize that the checkbox was not check and will not perform anything.

Comment: SOLVED: Ok this hopefully helps people who came across this post hoping to implement such treetable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not depending on IDs and the like to accomplish this behaviour. If you use HTML to properly describe the structure, it is easy to pick out the right elements in jQuery.

I made a quick example at http://jsfiddle.net/jRAcq/

Comment: I also wish that I can alter the layout and have li and ul tags in but the tree is running under jquery treetable that puts in td and trt

Comment: I see! Have a look at the new example I made: http://jsfiddle.net/7aEPr/ It uses one of the example tables from treeTable and recursively goes down the tree and looks for parent-children connections. Just make sure you get the id's and class names right.

Answer (score 1):

If i well understood I think you have to change

```
$('#update_ics_table').find('input:checkbox[id = "child-of-' + id + '"]')
```

with

```
$('#update_ics_table').find('input:checkbox[id ^= "child-of-' + id + '"]')
```

note the `^=` instead of `=`
I think the change is due because when you check the `system` checkbox you script is looking only for `child-of-SYSTEM` checkbox and not even for `child-of-SYSTEMspb`

Comment: *&*^ you are the best!! Works great now

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your code was not well formed, I have replaced Tables with different DOM structure

You checkout a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ch4nd4n/3e2hd/ and modify your code accordingly.
What code does is looks up for parent by class name, and uses id to search for DOM containing child checkboxes.

Simplified HTML

```
<div>
    <input class="ic_parent" id='1' type="checkbox" value="SYSTEM" />p1
    <ul class="ic_parent1">
        <li>
            <input class="ic_child" type="checkbox" value="SYSTEM" />c1
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="ic_child" type="checkbox" value="SYSTEM" />c2
        </li>
    ​​​</ul>
    <input class="ic_parent" id='2' type="checkbox" value="SYSTEM" />p2
    <ul class="ic_parent2">
        <li>
            <input class="ic_child" type="checkbox" value="SYSTEM" />c3
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="ic_child" type="checkbox" value="SYSTEM" />c4
        </li>
    </ul>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</div>
```

And Javascript to check or uncheck

```
$(".ic_parent").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $('.ic_parent' + $(this).attr('id')).find('.ic_child').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('.ic_parent' + $(this).attr('id')).find('.ic_child').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});​
```